# Laravel Confide ( Ardent )password confirmation works on save but not on update

Tags: php, validation, laravel, ardent

I know there are many questions about something similar, but I couldn't apply any solution to my problem.

I'm using Laravel with Confide, which uses Ardent to validate.

I don't have any problem saving users, password_confirmation is removed when inserted to the database (as it should) and users are inserted correctly.

The problem comes when trying to UPDATE a user. If I try to validate the user, I get an error saying that user is not unique:

```
public function storeProfile()
    {
        $user = $this->currentUser;
        $user->password = Input::get( 'password' );
        $user->password_confirmation = Input::get( 'password_confirmation' );
        //$user->updateUniques();
        $user->save();
        dd($user->errors()->all());

    }


string (31) "username is not unique"

string (28) "email is not unique"
```

If I try with $user->updateUniques() (as I saw in another question here in SO as a possible solution), it doesn't complain about uniqueness, but about password_confirmation not being present in the DB (so it's NOT removing it prior to inserting it).

```
public function storeProfile()
    {
        $user = $this->currentUser;
        $user->password = Input::get( 'password' );
        $user->password_confirmation = Input::get( 'password_confirmation' );
        $user->updateUniques();
        dd($user->errors()->all());

    }

 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'password_confirmation' in 'field list' (SQL: update `users` set `password` = y$wyNl2xMNJqL0mY4X766EfOvO.IKICyDfXckS1cas1Psj1TLwpJZWu, `updated_at` = 2014-03-07 17:13:04, `password_confirmation` = 123456 where `id` = 1)
```

I've tried with

public $autoPurgeRedundantAttributes = true;

```
public $forceEntityHydrationFromInput = false;
public $autoHydrateEntityFromInput = false;
```

As I saw in [Laravel/Ardent/User model editing + saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314130/laravel-ardent-user-model-editing-saving) but it's not working either. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out the reason I was getting an error was because I was using both updateUniques() and save(). This works:

```
public function storeProfile()
    {
        $user = $this->currentUser;
        $user->password = Input::get( 'password' );
        $user->password_confirmation = Input::get( 'password_confirmation' );
        $user->updateUniques();
        if ( !$user->errors()->all() ){
            return Redirect::action('UsuarioController@editProfile')
                ->with('success', 'Success!!');
        }
}
```